# SQL merge separate time stamps into 1 row per serial number

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, timestamp, pivot

I have tableA with columns SerialNumber(integer), LineNumber(integer), SectionNumber(integer), and TimeComplete(Datetime). This table tracks when a product with serial number x is completed at any given station on any given line. I am now trying to build a query that will show when any given station was completed for any given serial number, but the problem is I am receiving a line item per section completed. I want the output to be a single row with the serial number and then each section time stamped.

```
Current output
SerialNumber   Station1    Station2   Station3   Station4
123            TimeStamp   null       null       null
123            null        timestamp  null       null
123            null        null       timestamp  null
123            null        null       null       timestamp

Desired output
SerialNumber  Station1    Station2   Station3   Station4
123           TimeStamp   Timestamp  Timestamp  Timestamp
```

Current sql query

```
SELECT
distinct
tableA.Serial,
case when tableA.Section = 4 then tableA.TimeComplete
end as 'Station1',
case when tableA.Section = 5 then tableA.TimeComplete
end as 'Station2',
case when tableA.Section = 2 then tableA.TimeComplete
end as 'Station3',
case when tableA.Section = 6 then tableA.TimeComplete
end as 'Station4',
FROM tableA
```

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Microsoft server, sorry, should have mentioned that.

Comment: What happens if the number of `timestamp` values is different between different `SerialNumber` values?  This type of data pivoting is best done within your presentation layer, not the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do aggregation :

```
SELECT Serial
       MAX(case when Section = 4 then TimeComplete end) as 'Station1',
       MAX(case when Section = 5 then TimeComplete end) as 'Station2',
       MAX(case when Section = 2 then TimeComplete end) as 'Station3',
       MAX(case when Section = 6 then TimeComplete end) as 'Station4'
FROM tableA AS a
GROUP BY Serial;
```

Comment: This does work. I'm going to give it a few mins to see what/if other ideas come up and after that ill check it.